# How to set date as electron build version?

Tags: electron, electron-builder

I am using electron-builder to build a desktop application. I use below configuration in `package.json` file to build the app by electron-builder:

```
"scripts":{
    "dist": "build --em.mode=prod --em.version=07-24-2017"
}
```

The application can be built but I get below error when I launch it:

```
App version is not valid semver version: "24-07-2017
```

How can I set electron build version?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should pass the date with '.' separator, have you tried passing like this?

```
"scripts": {
     "dist": "build --em.mode=prod --em.version=07.24.2017" 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It uses [semver](http://semver.org/) checks to validate the number, so you can't use date as version, unfortunately.

Comment: As of electron-builder 23.0.3, this is no longer true.